# Nested tables not inlining when width is sufficient?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to design HTML emails and therefore getting a better grip around HTML tables.

I'm currently trying to create a layout with two nested tables that should be inline. The container is `600px` and the nested tables are `300px` each. When reducing the width of the nested tables to `290px`, the inlining works but I'd like to have it pixel perfect.

I tried to get rid of all the borders but I'm suspecting there is still a border attribute somewhere making the container smaller or the elements bigger than their specified width.

I'd love some help.

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="frame">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="column">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Content I
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="column">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Content II
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with inline there are automatic spaces between elements. See [How do I remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements).

You can avoid them by setting the `font-size` to 0 on your wrapper and re-assign it on your inner elements. Also reset the `padding`. I added the "row" class and put those styles on it, see the snippet below.

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
}

.row {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table width="100%" class="frame">
    <tr>
      <td class="row">
        <table class="column">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content I
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="column">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content II
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's possible I think the best approach would be using `flex` display on the tables' parent.

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
}

.column-container {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="frame">
  <tr>
    <td class="column-container">
      <table class="column">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Content I
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="column">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Content II
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`font-size: 0` is a good hack, but it forces you to remember about resetting `font-size` on children. It can be easy to forget and results with "disappearing text".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As stated above I'm working with emails which means flex-box and grid are not an option.